# Stripe - SKUS without a name are not supported by checkout

Tags: php, stripe-payments, sku

I'm implementing a stripe checkout system.

Every time i try to call checkout view i have a weird javascript error:
IntegrationError: SKUs for Checkout require a `name` attribute.

In dashboard the button for checkout integration is greyed out.

Any clues on how to pass the name in the creation of the SKU?

Here is my PHP for posting a SKU via stripe api curl call:

```
$sku = [
        'active' => 'true',
        'inventory' => ['type' => 'infinite', 'value' => null],
        "currency" => "eur",
        "price" => $price,
        "product" => $stripe_product_id
    ];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After many combinations, and deep analysis of stripe API, find the answer i was looking for.

Products Creation:

```
$pacoteSMS = [
        'name' => $name,
        'type' => 'good',
        'active' => 'true',
        'description' => $description,
        "attributes" => [
            "name"
        ],
    ];
```

SKU creation:

```
$sku = [
        'product' => $stripe_product_id,
        "attributes" => [
            "name" => $name,
        ],
        "price" => $price,
        "currency" => "eur",
        "inventory" => [
            "type" => "infinite",
        ],
        "active" => "true",
    ];
```

Comment: I can't figure out how to pass name attribute. I'm working with Laravel PHP, session code is in PHP and redirectToCheckout is in JS.

Answer (score 1):

The `name` value lives inside the `attributes` on the SKU object. You can set `attributes[name]` when creating or updating the SKU. For example:

'`attributes' => ['name' => 'the name'],`

Comment: When i use 'attributes' => ['name' => 'my_name'],
STRIPE API returns..........
'error' => [
  'message' => 'Unknown attributes specified: name',
  'param' => 'attributes',
  'type' => 'invalid_request_error'
 ]

Comment: In stripe api docs its written about attributes: A dictionary of attributes and values for the attributes defined by the product. If, for example, a product’s attributes are ["size", "gender"], a valid SKU has the following dictionary of attributes: {"size": "Medium", "gender": "Unisex"}.

Comment: The above explanation does not mention 'name' as a valid attribute for creating SKUS using the api endpoint.

Comment: @AndréCastro Could you elaborate on what the issue ended up being? Per your other answer, it appears you succeeded in setting the SKU's name in this manner.